# How to disable Intellij ide ternminal smart command suggestion?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have just got the update of Intellij ide and in terminal it provide me smart command suggestions.

How to disable ternminal smart command suggestion?

Comment: The "smart command suggestions" seems not clear for me. All terminal settings are in IntelliJ IDE `Preferences ... -> Tools -> Terminal`. In my setting, it's just pointing to my OS zsh. So it almost looks same as my native terminal.

Comment: It is an experimental feature at the moment. The documentation for it is work in progress.

Answer (score 2):

The last setting under **File | Settings | Tools | Terminal**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Double-click `Shift`(Windows)/`⇧`(macOS) to open *Search Everywhere*.
- Click the `Actions` tab, then enter `registry` to open the *Registry* window.

  [Registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhzS4.png)
- Find `terminal.shell.command.handling` and disable the value checkbox.

  [terminal.shell.command.handling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvLgc.png)